# How to create TCP proxy server with asyncio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, tcp, python-asyncio

I found these example with TCP client and server on asyncio: [tcp server example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#tcp-echo-server-protocol). But how to connect them to get TCP proxy server which will be receive data and send it to other adress?

Answer (score 18):

You can combine both [the TCP client and server examples](http://asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tcp_echo.html) from the [user documentation](http://asyncio.readthedocs.io).

You then need to connect the streams together using this kind of helper:

```
async def pipe(reader, writer):
    try:
        while not reader.at_eof():
            writer.write(await reader.read(2048))
    finally:
        writer.close()
```

Here's a possible client handler:

```
async def handle_client(local_reader, local_writer):
    try:
        remote_reader, remote_writer = await asyncio.open_connection(
            '127.0.0.1', 8889)
        pipe1 = pipe(local_reader, remote_writer)
        pipe2 = pipe(remote_reader, local_writer)
        await asyncio.gather(pipe1, pipe2)
    finally:
        local_writer.close()
```

And the server code:

```
# Create the server
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = asyncio.start_server(handle_client, '127.0.0.1', 8888)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

# Serve requests until Ctrl+C is pressed
print('Serving on {}'.format(server.sockets[0].getsockname()))
try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

# Close the server
server.close()
loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
loop.close()
```

Comment: And how to create this proxy with transports and create_server/create_connection?

Comment: Would it be possible to read the `local_reader` to get a specific header value form the actual request before opening the connection to `127.0.0.1:8889`

Comment: @SreenadhTC Definitely, it's up to the client handler to perform any kind of operation before forwarding the traffic.

Comment: @Vincent, Hey, Ya that is what I was trying to do, and I came up with an issue. I posted the same on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49106456/how-to-safely-read-readerstream-from-asyncio-without-breaking-the-stream)